# Could not fetch model of type 'HierarchicalEclipseProject'

Tags: java, eclipse

I am running Eclipse 4.5.1 and trying to import example code. I am using Gradle Integration for Eclipse 3.7.2 plugin.

When clicking on "Build Model" I get the error Could not fetch model of type 'HierarchicalEclipseProject'.

Here is the log:

```java
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable.run(GradleRunnable.java:112)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: repository not found: C:\Mario\Development\Hystrix\Hystrix-master
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.ExceptionUtil.coreException(ExceptionUtil.java:40)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.ExceptionUtil.coreException(ExceptionUtil.java:51)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.modelmanager.BuildResult.get(BuildResult.java:85)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.modelmanager.GradleProjectModelManager.getModelInternal(GradleProjectModelManager.java:145)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.modelmanager.GradleProjectModelManager.getModel(GradleProjectModelManager.java:100)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.modelmanager.GradleModelManager.getModel(GradleModelManager.java:77)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getSkeletalGradleModel(GradleProject.java:669)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.wizards.GradleImportWizardPageOne$11.doit(GradleImportWizardPageOne.java:499)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable.run(GradleRunnable.java:104)
... 1 more
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not fetch model of type 'HierarchicalEclipseProject' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.7-bin.zip'.
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:57)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
```